# Skype channel for azure chatbot

Tags: azure, botframework, skypedeveloper

when i use this code i got this errors [img1 ,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFRNw.png)[img 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9kzp.png)

```
<span class="skype-button bubble " data-bot-id="botid"></span>
<script src="https://swc.cdn.skype.com/sdk/v1/sdk.min.js"></script>
```

The same code seams to work in ie but not in any other browser.
I also tested with SSL certification but no chance.

How i could solve this problem.

I'm using azure web app bot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The web control feature you are using isn't actively supported, at this time. Additionally, it further limits some bot functionality. A better option is to utilize the [BotFramework-WebChat](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat) library by appending a webchat into your page. This utilizes Direct Line which, among other things, allows you to send messages/events between your page and the bot.

Check out this SO [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54089845/passing-querystring-to-microsoft-bot-web-channel/54100739#54100739) for a working example.

Hope of help!

Comment: thanks for your answer.the problem is my client wants the skype channels and it was working fine until recently